# About variables and screen touch events

Tags: java, android

I'm rather new to all this, so please bear with me.
what I want to do: interchange the position of two squares on the screen as soon as the user touches the screen.
what I've done so far: in my layout xml, I've used a frame layout end defined the two squares:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame1"
android:layout_width="260dp"
android:layout_height="540dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/square1"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textlines"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:text="@string/C1"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/square2"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textlines"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:text="@string/C2"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Then in Java, I've done the following:

```
        public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

EditText square1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.square1);

int cc1x = 210;
int cc1y = 410;

square1.setX(cc1x);
square1.setY(cc1y);

EditText square2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.square2);

int cc2x = 310;
int cc2y = 410;

square2.setX(cc2x);
square2.setY(cc2y);

int ccdumx = 410;
int ccdumy = 410;
}
```

In order to get the initial screen - so far so good. The two variables ccdumx and ccdumy are just there for an intermediate storage of one of the two squares when interchanging them
So now I add an event listener to detect a screen touch, followed by the changing of the coordinate variables:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ccdumx = cc1x;
    ccdumy = cc1y;
    cc1x = cc2x;
    cc1y = cc2y;
    cc2x = ccdumx;
    cc2y = ccdumy;

    square1.setX(cc1x);
    square1.setY(cc1y);
    square2.setX(cc2x);
    square2.setY(cc2y);
}
```

but then the variables aren't recognized, nor are the squares' names. When I declare them all again in this bloc, it does work, but then my logic only works one time; I can't switch the squares back, since the variables of the coordinates are always reset by the declaration, followed by the switch of positions... I'm kinda stuck here I was thinking maybe switching first to another activity, but then again, I might have the same problem there... Any help is most appreciated.
PS. I hope the formatting of the code turns out ok, first timer for me. If not, please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all these variables are local to method `onCreate()`. You need to define them globally to whole class, i.e. outside method `onCreate()`.

The java code in first block of your question should be changed to this.

```
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    int cc1x, cc1y, cc2x, cc2y, ccdumx, ccdumy;
    EditText square1, square2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

        square1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.square1);

        cc1x = 210;
        cc1y = 410;

        square1.setX(cc1x);
        square1.setY(cc1y);

        square2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.square2);

        cc2x = 310;
        cc2y = 410;

        square2.setX(cc2x);
        square2.setY(cc2y);

        ccdumx = 410;
        ccdumy = 410;
    }
//... rest of the code
```

Comment: meaning you have to declare them right after (to make the answer noob-friendly :P)
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {

Comment: This indeed answers the question, thank you very much ! I haven't got enough rep to vote your answers up, but if I had I would have done so.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make your variables Global
like this

```
EditText square1;
EditText square2;
int cc1x;
....

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    square1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.square1);
    .....
}
```